# Different behavior between String.value0f and Character.toString in Java

Tags: java, string, type-conversion

In the following example, this program snippet does not compile, but if we replace the method `Character.toString(char)` by `String.valueOf(char)`, everything is fine. What is the issue why Character.toString here ? In the documentation, these methods seem to have the same behavior. Thanks for explanation.

```
 public static void main (String args[]) {

 String source = "19/03/2016 16:34";

 String result = Character.toString(source.substring(1,3));
 System.out.print(result);

}
```

Comment: I don't understand. `Character.toString(...)` takes a `char`. You're giving a `String`. What did you expect?

Comment: The result of `source.substring(1,3)` is the 2-character String `"9/"`. What did you expect `Character.toString()` to do with that? Calling `String.valueOf()` on a String does nothing; it's already a String. Maybe you should read the javadoc of [`substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29)

Comment: @oukios `source.substring(1,3)` return a String .you can assign it no need of to string method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Character.toString(char c)` method accepts `char` value as an argument and you are passing a `String` class instance which is produced from `source.substring(1,3)` method. `String` and `char` are incompatible types, so compiler can't create correct method call and pass the value

Your code should be rewritten as:

```
public static void main (String args[]) {
    String source = "19/03/2016 16:34";
    String result = source.substring(1, 3);
    System.out.print(result);
    //equivalent to the previous System.out.println call
    System.out.print(source.substring(1, 3));
}
```

Also note that the first `substring` argument is an **inclusive** start index, the second one is **exclusive** end index and the leading index in Java String is 0 (not 1) exactly like in arrays (which is not a coincidence - String characters are stored in char array). So if you want to get a "19" String you should write `source.substring(0, 2)`

Comment: Thanks for your reply, everything is clear.

Comment: you're welcome! And don't forget to mark my answer as accepted to close a question :)

Answer (score 1):

What does the compiler error message say? Anyway, `source.substring(1,3)` gives you a `String` while `Character.toString()` needs a `char` and does not accept a `String`.

`String.valueOf(source.substring(1,3))` would call `String.valueOf(Object)`, not `String.valueOf(char)`.

You may obtain the same even simpler:

```
String result = source.substring(1,3);
```